# Image over Youtube video with a fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

Can anyone help me with some javascript here as I got no knowledge, but I have this idea...

This is what I have on my mind:

-I want an image to be over the youtube video. (image inside of css, so no img src please)
-On click of the image (image fades out) and video loads up and start playing.
-Once video is done *(I don't care if I have to add values of time when video will end manually)* the image will fade in again over the video.

I have found an script before that gives this option to put image over youtube video, but it did not had fade effect and it worked for 1 day only. Right now it doesnt works...

Cheers and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build a custome video player using the youtube api. You can handle any events you want, like start stop, pause etc. It's even possible to force the user to click a like button, ads or whatever. But it's a bit of work.